# installing matplotlib package for Python 2.7 on windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I already installed Python 2.7 on my PC (windows 7 with64 bit) using this web page(https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Finally when I tried in my new cell the followin program, it didn't work. So I think I should install numpy and mathplotlib packages.  I actually  tried as `pip install numpy matplotlib`, and it says it is already satisfied. But, it has not worked yet. How could I install alternatively by using `pip`? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for n in range(4):
 ax.plot(x, scipy.special.jn(n, x),
label=r"$J_%d(x)$" % n)
ax.legend();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Anaconda installation, please use their own package manager `conda`. In the terminal prompt, you should type

```
> conda update conda
> conda update anaconda
> conda install matplotlib
```

All of this is described in their [tutorial](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html)

UPDATE

your code work well (after I added plt.show()) with my Anaconda installation, producing
[image]

Comment: yes, it works for 'matplotlib'. But for 'numpy' and 'scipy', it says unknown. What can I do here? Thanks.

Comment: @Userabc this is strange. I have Anaconda 2.5.0 with Python 3.5, 64bit, and when I type `>conda install numpy` I get back `Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
numpy                     1.10.4                   py35_0`

Comment: @Userabc which means I already installed `numpy` some time ago. What message did you get back?

Comment: I got the same thing as you wrote except the last one. i.e. . instead of  #numpy 1.10.4 py35_0... it appears as "numpy ..... unknown"

Comment: @Userabc did you changed somehow environments? Could you do `conda info --envs` ? Link to environments http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: Really I appreciate your help. This is what I got:
[
C:\Users\Hailemariaam>conda install scipy
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Hailemariaam\Anaconda2:
#
scipy                     0.17.0              np110py27_0    <unknown>
C:\Users\Hailemariaam>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  C:\Users\Hailemariaam\Anaconda2
]

Comment: And what happens if you run in the terminal `> python` ? Looks like you have it installed, so maybe there is another version of python to interfere. After I type `> python` I would get `Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| ...`

Comment: Thank you so much.  It's okay now.